# Unable to properly decompress a binary in a tar.gz

Tags: go, gzip, tar

The below code tries to download and decompress a tar.gz file which in turn packs a binary inside it. The decompression seems to be going wrong since after the decompression is done and the file is there, the file is not being recognized as a binary executable by the system (Mac OS X).  I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me identify what is going wrong here.
Here's the code

```
        resp, err := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(S3Bucket),
            Key: aws.String(s3Key),
        })
        if err != nil { return err }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        ExtractTarGz(resp.Body)
```

```
func ExtractTarGz(gzipStream io.Reader) {
    uncompressedStream, err := gzip.NewReader(gzipStream)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ExtractTarGz: NewReader failed")
    }
    tarReader := tar.NewReader(uncompressedStream)
    for true {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Next() failed: %s", err.Error())
        }

        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            if err := os.Mkdir(header.Name, 0755); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Mkdir() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case tar.TypeReg:
            outFile, err := os.Create(header.Name)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Create() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("ExtractTarGz: Copy() failed: %s", err.Error())
            }
            outFile.Close()

        default:
            log.Fatalf(
                "ExtractTarGz: uknown type: %s in %s",
                header.Typeflag,
                header.Name)
        }

    }
}
```

(Normal unzipping the file from the tar file using Keka for Mac works fine and the resulting unzipped file is recognized as a binary. I have checked the file size, it's the same as that of the expected binary.
)

Comment: Is the `svc.getObject` function using the standard library http client? If so, and if you didn't change the transport or didn't disable compression, the downloaded file might already be extracted. The default implementation transparently extracts gzipped body.

Comment: After checking for the size of the downloaded file, I can confirm its the compressed file that is being downloaded.

Comment: @BurakSerdar no it doesn't. Decompressing gzip transfer-encoding is different from decompressing a body which is actually a gzip file. The HTTP client will do the former, but it won't do the latter unless the server is badly misconfigured (you would see the same problem in a browser).

Comment: Could this be a permissions issue - ie the created file is missing the executable bit?  Does it work if you `chmod +x` the file afterwards? If that's the issue, you will need to call outFile.Chown using the values in header.Mode to set the permissions that are stored in the tar archive.